# .htaccess URL Rewrite Breaks Relative Paths

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was attempting to remove the .html extension from my website URLs using a simple rewrite in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This however succeeded in rewriting the URL, but broke all relative paths I had on my page to access resources. This meant all my images, CSS files, scripts, etc. were broken and my page loaded improperly.

For example, had I tried to access a resource with the relative path of: ../scripts/script.js, the .htaccess rewrite would instead attempt to visit it at www.example.com/page/scripts/script.js.

I previously had this URL rewrite working along with relative paths so I know it is possible. I foolishly broke my .htaccess file and had no backups, so I have no clue how I did it and am unable to replicate it after hours of various different tries. Does anyone know how to remove the .html extension while still retaining relative paths?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: What is the correct path of js and css files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on htaccess files, but here's something you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html

 #remove php extension
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

[Article: Removing Extentions from URL with .htaccess](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: This works for .html files. Is there anyway to make this work with both .html and .php simultaneously? I tried just copying/pasting and editing the code, but it only works for the block of code located closer to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set base url in the header of your html

```
<base href="//yourdomain/" />
```

And if you are working on localhost

```
<base href="//localhost/yourdomain/" />
```

Comment: CORS problem with <BASE